# Is it possible to put scale(ex; 1:10000) at print composer on QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: qgis, printing

I would like to display a cartographic scale (e.g. 1:10,000) in the print composer.

I can set the scale from map tab.
After setting, I can type by myself as Label.

Is it possible to put scale automatically??

Answer (score 14):

Yes, that's possible: Add a scale bar object to the map and change it's type to numeric. That will display the scale.

Comment: I got numeric!! Appreciate!!

Comment: @JermainMarthin Please accept this answer if it solves your issue.